# Vue clickthrough event is not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a chart inside a Vue directive. I want to catch the click through event, do something, and pass it through as usual.

Putting the following:

```
v-on:click="clickThrough($event)"
```

with

```js
methods: {
  clickThrough: function (event) {
    var a = 1
    return event
  }
}
```

And a breakpoint at the `var a = 1`.

However the breakpoint does not get hit. Something else must be catching the click event.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```html
v-on:click.native="clickThrough($event)"
```

From the docs:

> There may be times when you want to listen directly to a native event on the root element of a component. In these cases, you can use the .native modifier for v-on

Child components have to emit an event for the parent component to catch it in a listener, and no such `click` event is emitted by the custom component.  This is unlike a non-component element such as a plain div sitting directly in the parent, which does emit the event.  So `.native` is there for exactly this situation.